# An alias in .bashrc fails vs command line succeeds

Tags: bash, shell, alias

I run this from a user's home dir to show me the most recent files while omitting the shell profile files:

```
find ./ -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n"|grep -vP "/\.(bash|emacs|gtkrc|kde/|zshrc)" |sort -n| tail -10|cut -f2- -d" "|while read EACH; do ls -l "$EACH"; done;
```

This works, but just not as well when placed in my .bashrc as an alias:

```
alias recentfiles='find ./ -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n"|grep -vP "/\.\(bash|emacs|gtkrc|kde/|zshrc\)"|sort -n| tail -10|cut -f2- -d" "|while read EACH; do ls -l "$EACH"; done;'
```

In the image you see the results without doing any filtering, followed by the desired result using `grep -v` for filtering which works on command line. Then final result - only partially succeeds in weeding out those files.

I have tried using bash_ and [b]ash. Not even bas (which fails to even get .basin) work ?!? And also I can use macs or acs AND still get the .emacs omitted so obviously the syntax in my alias is not respecting the /. either. Not a problem with reserved words as I originally thought.

[image: Terminal screenshot]

I *DO* get the expected results if I place my original command as is in a file and then use the alias that way:
**alias recentfiles='. /root/mycommands/recentfiles'**

Can someone explain or point me to a reference to understand what is at play here? I wouldn't know what phrase with the proper terms to search on.

Comment: Why aren't you telling `find` to filter those out instead?

Comment: Use a functions instead ;)

Comment: creating an alias implies that the shell scans that command line and does it magic on single and dbl-quoted strings. It's very difficult to understand what "state" that cmd string is in (what quote and escape chars have been consumed and which are still there) after it has been activated by processing. Its really not worth your time trying to fix an alias, much better to use functions, they are debuggable, they can take run-time arguments, and you don't have to trick the shell parser to get them to work. All IMHO, so good luck.

Comment: Use `! \( -name .bash -o -name .emacs -o ... \)` in the `find` command instead of `grep`.

Comment: When you write "in the image, you see", I assume you tried to post an image, but somehow haven't been able to. That's fine, it's much better to copy-paste the terminal output directly anyway.

Comment: @shellter thank you for explaining. I shall tweak it to be a function instead and switch to using find to filter it. I did upload an image and the imgur URL shows in the edit box. Trry once more this way: [link]https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHhOy.png

Comment: An `alias` only supports assignment of a **simple command**.  Your `while` **loop** is a **compound command**. Put all that stuff `find ./ ...; done` in a function and then assign the function name to the alias. (or just call the function)

Comment: BTW, if you want to have a more concrete idea of what's going wrong when the alias is executed, use `set -x` to tell the shell to log the commands it runs, then compare the line logged to stderr from the faulty invocation with the working one.

Comment: BTW, from [meta], some explanation of why copied/pasted textual transcripts are preferred to images: [Why not upload images of code when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problems:

```
alias recentfiles='find ./ -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n"|grep -vP "/\.(bash|emacs|gtkrc|kde/|zshrc)"|sort -n| tail -10|cut -f2- -d" "|while read EACH; do ls -l "$EACH"; done;'
```

The issue is with `grep -P`, where -P makes it use the perl regular expressions. In perl there is no need to use \ in grouping. So `(bash|emacs|...)` instead of `\(bash|emacs|...\)` . I really doubt it worked outside of .bashrc, unless you have some alias for `grep` which make it behave differently outside of `.bashrc`.

As other have said in the comments, your filtering is inefficient. Better rewrite your command with:

```
find ./ \( -name ".bash*" -o -name ".emacs*" -o -name .gtkrc -o -name .kde -o -name .zshrc \) -prune -o \( -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" \) |sort -n| tail -10|cut -f2- -d" "| tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 ls -l;
```

This way it will not waste time searching files inside `.emacs.d/` or inside `.kde/`, and will immediately prune the search. Also, `xargs -0 ls -l` is so much shorter and clearer than the while loop.

To avoid issues with filenames that contain newlines, better use \0 characters, that are never part of a file name:

```
find ./ \( -name ".bash*" -o -name .emacs -o -name .gtkrc -o -name .kde -o -name .zshrc \) -prune -o \( -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0" \) |sort -n -z | tail -z -n -10| cut -z -f2- -d" " | xargs -0 ls -l
```

Comment: `xargs ls -l` will misbehave with filenames with spaces: If you have a file named `foo bar`, you'll be running `ls -l "foo" "bar"`. At barest minimum, use `xargs -d $'\n' ls -l` to be correct for filenames with spaces or quotes; better to rewrite the rest of the pipeline to use NUL delimiters to be correct for filenames with literal newlines as well.

Comment: Yes, correct. But the whole printf "%T@ %p\n" suffers from a similar problem. It will not work with newlines. I'll replace \n with \0 and xargs with xargs -0,

Comment: Fixed the issue with \n in the file name, by using \0 as the line terminator

Answer (score 0):

#### Part 1: Fixing The Issue

**Use a function instead.**

There are several major issues with aliases:

- Because you pass your content to be string-prefixed inside quotes when creating an alias, it's parsed differently than it would be when typed directly at the command line.
- Because an alias is simple prefix substitution, they don't have their own arguments (`$1`, `$2`, etc); they don't have a call stack; debugging mechanisms like `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+'; set -x` can't tell you which file code from an alias originated in; etc.
- Aliases are an interactive feature; POSIX doesn't mandate that shells support them at all, and they're turned off by default during script execution.

Functions solve all these problems.

```
recentfiles() {
  find ./ \
      '(' -name '.bash*' -o -name '.emacs*' -o -name .gtkrc -o -name .kde -o -name .zshrc ')' -prune \
      -o -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0" |
    sort -nz |
    tail -z -n -10 |
    while read -d' ' _ && IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
      printf '%s\0' "$file"
    done |
    xargs -0 ls -ld --
}
```

Note that I also made several other changes:

- Instead of using `\n` as a separator, the above code uses `\0`. This is because newlines can be found in filenames; a file that contained newlines in its name could look like any number of files, with any arbitrary sizes it wanted, to the rest of your pipeline. (Unfortunately, POSIX doesn't require that `sort` and `tail` support newline delimiters, so the `-z` options used above are GNUisms).
- Instead of using `grep -v` to remove dotfiles, I used the `-prune` option to `find`. This is particularly important for directories like `.kde`, since it stops `find` from spending the time and I/O bandwidth to recurse down directories for which you intend to throw the results away anyhow.
- For documentation of the importance of the `IFS=` and `-r` arguments used in the `while read` loop, see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Both of these improve behavior in presence of unusual filenames (clearing IFS prevents trailing whitespace from being stripped; passing `-r` prevents literal backslashes from being elided).
- Instead of `grep -P` -- a GNU extension which is only available if `grep` was compiled with libpcre support -- my first cut (prior to moving to `find -prune`) switched to `grep -E`, which is adequately expressive, much more widely available, and [lends itself to higher performance implementations](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html).

---

#### Part 2: Explaining The Issue

Running your alias after `set -x`, we see:

```
+ find ./ -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n'
+ grep -vP '/\.\(bash|emacs|gtkrc|kde/|zshrc\)'
+ sort -n
+ tail -10
+ cut -f2- '-d '
+ read EACH
```

By contrast, running the command it was intended to wrap, we see:

```
+ find ./ -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n'
+ grep -vP '/\.(bash|emacs|gtkrc|kde/|zshrc)'
+ sort -n
+ tail -10
+ cut -f2- '-d '
+ read EACH
```

In the command itself, there are no literal backslashes before `(` and `)`.